# Node.js and Socket.IO - How to reconnect as soon as disconnect happens

Tags: node.js

I'm building a small prototype with node.js and socket.io.  Everything is working well, the only issue I'm facing is that my node.js connection will disconnect and I'm forced to refresh the page in order to get the connection up and running again.

Is there a way to reestablish the connection as soon as the disconnect event is fired?

From what I've heard, this is a common issue. So, I'm looking for a best-practice approach to solving this problem :)

Thanks very much,
Dan

Comment: Please see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656265/3904109 For Android Client Side

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**edit: Socket.io has builtin-support now**

When I used socket.io the disconnect did not happen(only when i closed the server manually). But you could just reconnect after say for example 10 seconds on failure or something on disconnect event.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   // reconnect
});
```

I came up with the following implementation:

**client-side javascript**

```
var connected = false;
const RETRY_INTERVAL = 10000;
var timeout;

socket.on('connect', function() {
  connected = true;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  socket.send({'subscribe': 'schaftenaar'});
  content.html("<b>Connected to server.</b>");
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  connected = false;
  console.log('disconnected');
  content.html("<b>Disconnected! Trying to automatically to reconnect in " +                   
                RETRY_INTERVAL/1000 + " seconds.</b>");
  retryConnectOnFailure(RETRY_INTERVAL);
});

var retryConnectOnFailure = function(retryInMilliseconds) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!connected) {
        $.get('/ping', function(data) {
          connected = true;
          window.location.href = unescape(window.location.pathname);
        });
        retryConnectOnFailure(retryInMilliseconds);
      }
    }, retryInMilliseconds);
  }

// start connection
socket.connect();
retryConnectOnFailure(RETRY_INTERVAL);
```

**serverside(node.js):**

```
// express route to ping server.
app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.send('pong');
});
```

Comment: It'd be nice to just reconnect the socket. Also, you never set `timeout`.

Comment: @Nornagon I reconnect to the socket? Also in your implementation you just try to connect to the socket again. But you got disconnected for a reason?

Comment: @Alfred - you reload the whole web page. I did get disconnected for a reason, but I still want to keep retrying until that reason goes away (i.e. the server comes back up :))

Comment: @Nornagon I do not reload the whole webpage. Have you even used the code? I use simple ajax request to test availability of webservice!

Comment: What does `window.location.href = unescape(window.location.pathname)` do?

Comment: o aha that :P. That's because the express server is running again so when can fetch the latest data. On the older version of socket.io doing multiple socket.connect would result in strange behaviour. But that is probably fixed now...

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking a dumb question @Alfred, but your last comment still doesn't answer nornagon's question (in last comment) for me and I have the same question.

Comment: @Andrew problem has been fixed in latest socket.io so you do not have to worry about that. See Norgagon's updated answer => http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149185/11926

Comment: @Alfred I see that it has been fixed. I'm still wondering what that line of javascript did. `window.location.href = unescape(window.location.pathname)`

Comment: O that. First we do an AJAX request to /ping to tell if the server is up and running again. If that is established we just reload the page. I think that I could have written that cleaner(window.location.reload()??), but that did the job back then!

Comment: @Alfred - What is the advantage of using this compared to a simple  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   socket.connect();
});

Comment: @mad.geek you would get infinite callbacks when server is down blowing up your stack probably. Also this code is obsolete now, because socket.io does support it now.

Comment: @Alfred  What if I want to have socket.io reconnect by itself say 10 times and then it fails and i would use this code to check every 10 seconds if the connection is back up . Will this be recommended ?

Comment: I think you could use something like that. P.S: From socket.io documentation it uses exponential back off algorithm first.

Answer (score 106):

**EDIT**: socket.io now has [built-in reconnection support](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io-client). Use that.

e.g. (these are the defaults):

```
io.connect('http://localhost', {
  'reconnection': true,
  'reconnectionDelay': 500,
  'reconnectionAttempts': 10
});
```

<s>This is what I did:</s>

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('reconnecting...')
  socket.connect()
})
socket.on('connect_failed', function () {
  console.log('connection failed. reconnecting...')
  socket.connect()
})
```

It seems to work pretty well, though I've only tested it on the websocket transport.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include an example, and changed the link to point to the `socket.io-client` repository. There's additional documentation there.

Comment: documented at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#new-managerurl-options

Comment: Attempts is 'infinity' by default https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#reconnectionattempts

Answer (score 6):

### Start reconnecting even if the first attempt fails

If the first connection attempt fails, **socket.io 0.9.16** doesn't try to reconnect for some reason. This is how I worked around that.

```
//if this fails, socket.io gives up
var socket = io.connect();

//tell socket.io to never give up :)
socket.on('error', function(){
  socket.socket.reconnect();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works for me (but I use socket.socket.connect(); rather than reconnect) !

Answer (score 1):

I know this has an accepted answer, but I searched forever to find what I was looking for and thought this may help out others.

If you want to let your client attempt to reconnect for infinity (I needed this for a project where few clients would be connected, but I needed them to always reconnect if I took the server down).

```
var max_socket_reconnects = 6;

var socket = io.connect('http://foo.bar',{
    'max reconnection attempts' : max_socket_reconnects
});

socket.on("reconnecting", function(delay, attempt) {
  if (attempt === max_socket_reconnects) {
    setTimeout(function(){ socket.socket.reconnect(); }, 5000);
    return console.log("Failed to reconnect. Lets try that again in 5 seconds.");
  }
});
```

Comment: "reconnectionAttempts":"Infinity"