# SocketIO Server doesnt handle fired event from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the event handler `window.onunload` the client fires event:

```
function onPageUnload() {
   userSocket.emit('command', "{'cloudBackup': 'cancel'}");
}
```

On the server I have a listener:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("RIKO ::: SocketIO connected!");

    socket.on('command', function(msg) {
        console.log("RIKOO ::: command with msg : " + msg);
        backupOnceProcCanceled = true;
        console.log("PC = " + backupOnceProcCanceled)
        // throw new Error("RIKO ::: Thrown Error at backup2.js line 106")
    });

    socket.on( 'disconnect', function(reason) {
        console.log("RIKO ::: SocketIO disconnected! Reason : " + reason );
    })
})
```

When the client refresh/leave/navigate the page I see that the browser fires the event 
`('command', "{'cloudBackup': 'cancel'}")`

But the server doesn't detect the event. Only when the port is closed:

> RIKO ::: SocketIO disconnected! Reason : transport close

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150700/socket-io-disconnection-problem-before-closing-window but it might also just be that asynchronous actions aren't required to be finished when a window's js stops. Note that doing actions on closing a window is a bad practice on the web

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard you are using isn't a valid way of catching all events. You can write a little middleware to catch those:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("RIKO ::: SocketIO connected!");

    socket.use((packet, next) => {
        console.log("RIKOO ::: command with msg : " + msg);
        backupOnceProcCanceled = true;
        console.log("PC = " + backupOnceProcCanceled)
        // throw new Error("RIKO ::: Thrown Error at backup2.js line 106")
        next();
    });

    socket.on( 'disconnect', function(reason) {
        console.log("RIKO ::: SocketIO disconnected! Reason : " + reason );
    })
})
```

The `socket.use()` function has been added for this purpose specifically. You can take a look at the documentation at the following link: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn

Or alternatively you can catch this particular event by just changing the `*` to `command`.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange but inserting delay in `"onPageUnload"` function solved the problem.

```
function waitMs(ms) {
   var start = Date.now()
   var now = start;
   while(now - start < ms){
       now = Date.now()
   }
}

function onPageUnload() { //window.onunload = onPageUnload;
   userSocket.emit('command', "{'cloudBackup': 'cancel'}");
   waitMs(50);
   console.log("SOCKET send cloudBackup cancel 1 ");
}
```

I am saying strange because the event should be handled despite the delay.
May be when the page is being reloaded the Server load is high and before it can handle the event the port is already closed.

Still not sure.