# Disconnecting and manually reconnecting Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm initiating a socket connection using Socket.IO to a Node.js server and it's as simple as follows:

```
var socket = io.connect(url, options);
```

At some point, I need to disconnect this socket when it's no longer need and reconnect it. I'm having some issues initiating a completely new socket and I thought it would be much better to simply reconnect the same socket rather then rebuilding another socket and adding listeners to it.

Based on the socket.io documentation, I should be able to manually reconnect a socket by calling:

```
socket.connect();
```

But when I call that method, I'm getting an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to provide more code. It seems a problem of scope.

Comment: Alexander, it's not a scope issue. The connect socket function is simply not supported as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

You should call the socket in your `socket` object :

```
var socket = io.connect(url, options);
socket.socket.connect();
```

See this question it is related : [Socket IO reconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437584/socket-io-reconnect/10443120#10443120)