# Socket.io connection does not when i change my wifi network

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am using node.js + socket.io for a chat application. I noticed that when i change my wifi connection, the socket stops working.

How can i get this to work?

Here is my client side connection code

```
var socket = io.connect("https://website.com:8080", {
            'reconnection delay': 500, 
            'reconnection limit': Infinity, 
            'max reconnection attempts': Infinity 
              });
```

Comment: Do you mean it didn't reconnection when you switch to another wifi?

Comment: yeah. when i change wifi connection it doesnt connect

Answer (score 3):

You can use the socket.io disconnect event to make your own reconnect:

```
var socket = connectToServer();
function connectToServer(){
     var socket = io.connect("https://website.com:8080", {
        'reconnection delay': 500, 
        'reconnection limit': Infinity, 
        'max reconnection attempts': Infinity 
     });
     return socket;
 }

 socket.on('disconnect', function(){
     socket.socket.connect();
 });
```

: )

Comment: i already have that in my code... but it does not work for me. as in disconnect is not immediately fired from the server on network change.

Comment: Sorry, I makes a mistake. The sencond times connect should use the method socket.socket.connect(); Here is a related [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437584/socket-io-reconnect/10443120#10443120)

Comment: thats good.. but how should i be able to reconnect as soon as network changes?

Comment: Well, you can use the window.offline/online detection to manual disconnect and reconnect.  Here is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events)    and here is the [demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/FP4ZY/)

Comment: thanks.. i will try this and let you know what happens

Comment: The window.offline/online character only works in browser support html5. Hope this can meet your need. : )

Comment: Hey.. I just noticed that this code leads to multiple socket connections on the same window/tab.. is there any way to avoid that? the socket does not disconnect if a person disconnects and connects to the same wifi again.

Comment: Yep, you can add a disconnect event on the server side to remove the handlers. So the next the connect that will be a new connect. Can this work for you?

Comment: Ok, I will give the demo code later. Cause I don't have a laptop now. By the way, do you write your sever in nodejs or sth others?

Comment: @user3455531 I just Try to make a wifi disconnect&reconnect, then my websocket reconnect will make a multiple connects. But after about 10 seconds the server side will disconnect the 'lost-connect' client. So I think you don't need to think about it. You can log the client socket handler like this [Demo Code](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/ehH4y/). Then you will see the 'disconnect' happen in server side. : )

Comment: The problem arises when the wifi goes for a few seconds and then come back... it connects to the previous socket again and opens a new socket as well

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean the client side connect previous again and open a new socket? The server side will auto disconnect when it cannot get a heartbeat response from client. So if your client reconnect with this [demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/FP4ZY/). After a few seconds, the server side will auto disconnect previous connection.

Comment: Hey.. it works now, but i have another problem... sometimes when i reconnect again, the socket disconnects again after 60-120 seconds. and it keeps reconnecting and disconnecting. I get the error "client not handshaken" in the socket.on('error') function

Comment: I see that when the new socket is connected and the previous socket disconnects, it triggers the disconnect function on client side again, which results into another connection.. so the loop continues

Comment: Could you show me the demo code in jsfiddle or somewhere else? Cuz' I just make a similar reconnect function. But I don't get this error...

Comment: @user3455531 I'm so sorry!!! My demo code have make a big mistake. I just make a own test in switch wifi to reconnect. Then I noticed that when I set the connect option: 'reconnection limit' and others, the socket.io will reconnect by itself. And my code 'on diconnect' to connect again is not right. After I create a switch wifi demo, [here is the demo code that works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/yMbqj/4/). My apologiesssssssss... T.T

Comment: @user3455531 maybe you can add my google plus(tyler.z.yang@gmail.com) to talk about this code?