# socket.io need to reregister handlers on reconnect

Tags: javascript, socket.io

With socket.io is it necessary to reregister event handlers on receipt of a `reconnect` event by using `socket.on`? Or are the handlers from the previous connection automatically used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437584/socket-io-reconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't manually create a whole new socket.io object yourself, the event handlers will stay in place during the normal auto-reconnect logic that socket.io uses.

The socket.io auto-reconnect is meant to be completely transparent to your code unless you are specifically observing the reconnection event.