# Stop socket.io from reconnecting

Tags: socket.io

Simple scenario:

1. Client connects to server with socket.io (`socket = io.connect(...)`)
2. Server crashes
3. Client tries to reconnect
4. User tells client to disconnect (`socket.disconnect()`)
5. Server starts
6. Client reconnects

It seems that once socket.io starts attempting to reconnect, it cannot be stopped anymore. I want step 4 to prevent step 6 from happening, but it doesn't. What do I have to call instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might want to handle the reconnection yourself.

```
// Disables the automatic reconnection
var socket = io.connect('http://server.com', {
    reconnection: false
});

// Reconnects on disconnection
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.connect(callback);
});
```

Note: old versions used `reconnect` instead of `reconnection`.

Comment: It seems that currently the option has changed to `reconnection: false` [link](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object))

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is to [configure](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) `socket.io` `client` to not `reconnect` is set property `reconnect` to `false`

I created a little server(`server.js`) to test this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Then I created this `test.js` to test that it does not reconnect

```
var client = require('socket.io-client'),
    socket = client.connect('http://localhost:8888', {
        'reconnect': false
    });

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
});
```

For `test.js` to work you will need to install `socket.io-client` from `npm` issuing `npm install socket.io-client` or by adding `socket.io-client` (dev-)`dependency` to your `package.json`.

When I stop `server.js` while `test.js` is running `test.js` will return immediately which I believe is your desired result. When I set `reconnect` to `true` the client will try to reconnect to server which is not the desired behaviour

Comment: But I want it to reconnect - until I tell it explicitly to disconnected, then it should stop trying.

Comment: Okay. I think you should write that logic yourself. It should not be that hard. I wrote some logic like that myself in the past which will continue to retry => http://stackoverflow.com/a/4433929/11926

Comment: Thank you for your effort! You are right, it's not that hard.
Still think it's a bug in socket.io, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a new socket.io 1.1.x you can do the following:

```
var manager = io.Manager('http://localhost:9823', { autoConnect: false });
```

Here is [blog link](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-1-1-0/).

Comment: the link to the blog is dead

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
self.socket?.manager?.reconnects = false
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This one works great for me, though , it shoots one more attempt before stops completely.

socket.io-client": "2.2.0"

`this.socket.io.reconnectionAttempts(0);`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution, in order to avoid reconnection only when I needed and not globally using the socket options, was to call `disconnect()` method on `disconnect` event:

```js
socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  socket.disconnect();
  socket = null;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just call `socket.disconnect()`, then it will stop trying to reconnect.