# socket.io client reconnect timeout

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with node.js and I like the solution. The only issue I notice is around a disconnection and reconnection.

These are my current settings:

```
  'connect timeout': 1000,
  'reconnect': true,
  'reconnection delay': 300,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10000,
  'force new connection':true
```

I notice if I stop and start the node.js process the client connects back fine and quickly, however if the server is offline for a couple of minutes the client either never reconnects or takes a very long (non-user friendly) amount of time to.

I wanted to ask if there is anything I've missed or could add to the socket.io configuration to keep the client polling for a reconnection.

I know 'reconnection delay':

> reconnection delay defaults to `500` ms
>
> The initial timeout to start a reconnect, this is increased using an
>   exponential back off algorithm each time a new reconnection attempt
>   has been made.

But the exponential effect its not very user friendly. Is there a way to keep checking for a connection every X period of time - eg: 5 seconds.

If not I guess I can write some client side JS to check the connect and attempt reconnections if needed but it would be nice if the socket.io client offered this.

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: See answer below for proper approach

I am afraid that the reconnection algorithm cannot be modified (as of December 2013); the [Github issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/226) to allow this feature is not merged yet. However, one of the commentors is suggesting a small workaround, which should nullify the exponential increase:

> `socket.socket.reconnectionDelay /= 2` on `reconnecting`

The other approach is, as you said, to write some client-side code to overwrite the reconnecting behavior, and do polling. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432271/node-js-and-socket-io-how-to-reconnect-as-soon-as-disconnect-happens) of how this could be done.

EDIT: the above code will have to go inside the 'disconnect' event callback:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      socket.socket.reconnectionDelay /= 2;
  });
});
```

Comment: is there any information on where the workaround above goes in the code? clientside I assume but where in the code?

Comment: The workaround would go inside your 'disconnect' event handler. Check my edit

Answer (score 21):

There is a configuration option, `reconnection limit` (see [Configuring Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)):

> **reconnection limit** defaults to `Infinity`
>
> - The maximum reconnection delay in milliseconds, or Infinity.

It can be set as follows:

```
io.set("reconnection limit", 5000);
```

When set, the reconnection delay will continue to increase (according to the exponential back off algorithm), but only up to the maximum value you specify.

Comment: This answers the question exactly and should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution I went with - when the socket disconnects it enters a loop that keeps trying to reconnect every 3 seconds until the connection is created - works a treat:

```
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socketConnectTimeInterval = setInterval(function () {
      socket.socket.reconnect();
      if(socket.socket.connected) {clearInterval(socketConnectTimeInterval);}
    }, 3000);
  });
```

cheers