# Multiple Instances error on Socket IO disconnect from the client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

My team is using socket.io for implementing chat on our app. We are using nodejs on server side.
Our chat is working fine on proper internet connection but having trouble whenever there is a change in internet connectivity.
The problem is when there is sudden internet connection loss on client, disconnect event is not triggered on server side immediately.
It is called after pingInterval+ pingTimeout. But if device gets internet back before the disconnect event is triggered(server-side) it will try to connect again and at the server we do not allow two connections for same session(server is still maintaining its first connection) due to which error is thrown and device will not try to reconnect until its killed.
Which means even if app is opened our chat will not work if there is a fluctuation in internet connection.
Has anyone faced this problem earlier. Please give your suggestions.

If there is any way to send reconnect-error or connect-error from server when client is trying to connect then this can be solved as on client side reconnection will be tried on connect-error or reconnect-error but not on simple error.

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432271/node-js-and-socket-io-how-to-reconnect-as-soon-as-disconnect-happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js and Socket.IO - How to reconnect as soon as disconnect happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432271/node-js-and-socket-io-how-to-reconnect-as-soon-as-disconnect-happens)

Comment: try to build an array on server side, each element of the array shoud contain: 1. the session id, 2. the socket.id  Then, whenever a disconnect happens, search for the array with the socket.id and delete that element.  Whenever a connect event happens, search for the array with the session id and, if found, disconnect the socket from server side, if not  found, add an element to the array.